# sine curve animation draw java Canvas is slow

Tags: javascript, java, html, animation, canvas

I built a sine curve with a for loop and built a render into the for loop. the problem is the animation is very slow because it is tied with a for loop. how can I solve the problem?

```
enter code here
     AnimationTimer = new Timer() {
     @Override
     public void run() { 
         RenderAnimation();  
     }
 }; 
 AnimationTimer.scheduleRepeating(1);
 
 Hintergrundbild = CreateCanvasElementBackground(); 
 
  };

 
 private void RenderAnimation() {  
    if (RUN_ANIM == true){  
        if (k < 720){
            
            
            k++;
        
        
        
        }else{
            
            k=0;}  
    }
    this.DrawFrame();
 }
 
 private void DrawFrame(){  
 
 for (double i = 0; i < 720; i = i+0.5){  
     valh = Math.sin(i*Math.PI/180);    
     h_tmp2 = ch*0.023*valh*5+ch*0.4;
     double m = i+k;
     if(i+k>719){m = m-720;} 
       
       
     Off.setStrokeStyle(colorGreen);
     Off.beginPath();
     Off.moveTo(Math.ceil(cw*0.350+cw*0.00025*m)+0.5, Math.ceil(h_tmp2)+0.5);       // Gerade
     Off.lineTo(Math.ceil(cw*0.351+cw*0.00025*m)+0.5, Math.ceil(h_tmp2)+0.5);    
     Off.closePath();
     Off.stroke();
     
     }
  }
```

I built a sine curve with a for loop and built a render into the for loop. the problem is the animation is very slow because it is tied with a for loop. how can I solve the problem?
I built a sine curve with a for loop and built a render into the for loop. the problem is the animation is very slow because it is tied with a for loop. how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you want a slow animation or shall it be painted as fast as possible?

Comment: Please post a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If it's all one curve, you could begin your path outside the loop and only do `lineTo` inside the loop and close the path at the end.

Comment: I want fast animation, now animation is extremely slow because it is tied with for loop. So I built a sine curve with a for loop and that leads to slow animation. I either have to draw a different sine curve or change the type of animation.